GitHub Action Error MSB1009 Project File is Not Found
I have set up deploy.yml as follows
name: Deploy to Azure Linux App Service

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: '8.0.x' # Adjust according to your project needs.

    - name: Build project
      run: dotnet build ../../CS/WinForms.Client/WinForms.Client.csproj --configuration Release

    - name: Publish project
      run: dotnet publish -c Release -o publish_output

    - name: Azure Login
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}

    - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: DxMiddleCApp # Replace with your Azure Web App name
        slot-name: production
        package: ./publish_output

When I try to run I get an error

Run dotnet build ../../CS/WinForms.Client/WinForms.Client.csproj
--configuration Release MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist. Switch: ../../CS/WinForms.Client/WinForms.Client.csproj Error:
Process completed with exit code 1.

My Repository looks like this

I cant see where I have gone wrong.
Co-Pilot is taking me in circles

The CS directory is on the same path after checkout so ../../ is making it an invalid path. Removing ../../ should fix this issue. Apart from that, the older versions of actions are being used. You might want to update those manually or, better yet, configure Dependabot to automate this. See Keeping your actions up to date with Dependabot for more details.

TL;DR
Like already mentioned in the comments, removing ../../ from the path pointing to the project file should be enough.
dotnet build CS/WinForms.Client/WinForms.Client.csproj
Explanation
Expanding on the answer on the comments with a bit of background.
First, the checkout part.
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

As mentioned in the documentation, actions/checkout "checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your workflow can access it."
What's $GITHUB_WORKSPACE then? Well, again according to documentation:

GITHUB_WORKSPACE  The default working directory on the runner for steps, and the default location of your repository when using the checkout action. For example, /home/runner/work/my-repo-name/my-repo-name.

Alright, so in other words, $GITHUB_WORKSPACE is the directory where your commands get executed and where your code is checked out.
Now, when you do this:
    - name: Build project
      run: dotnet build ../../CS/WinForms.Client/WinForms.Client.csproj --configuration Release

you are clearly assuming that the working directory is the directory of the workflow file, which is not the case. Instead, GH actions parses the workflow and then executes the steps on the repository root.
This is why this should work:
    - name: Build project
      run: dotnet build CS/WinForms.Client/WinForms.Client.csproj --configuration Release

See also official GH actions dotnet example.
